# Fluent Nhibernate mapping to avoid null references

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have an `Order` entity and a `CreditCard` entity.

The `Order` can have 0 or 1 `CreditCards`.

The `CreditCard` can have 1 or more `Orders`

I understand this to be a one-to-many relationship. BUT we anticipate for the majority of `Orders` to not be paid using a `CreditCard`, hence the Order table will be full of null references. My understanding being that this is a bad practice.

Is it possible to design the database/entities/mappings some other way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm curious, why is it a bad practice to have a table with lots of nulls?

Comment: Isn't it? To be honest I think I am over thinking this problem and wasting my time...

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't, but I fail to see why. I'm not confident enough in my DB knowledge to say that it's definitely ok, though.

Comment: If you really want to avoid that, you can treat it as many-to-many relationship.

Comment: most my experience on the subject comes from university + internet, so I don't claim an expertise. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336687/how-can-i-avoid-nulls-in-my-database-while-also-representing-missing-data) which is impossible with my nhibernate knowledge :(

Comment: @driushkin i did this for a similar problem. But I don't like using a list to represent a single object. Plus it created a host of other problems with mvc that I want to avoid.

Comment: @Circadian: Thanks a lot. So, the problem is 3-valued logic. Won't a boolean column `HasCreditCard` solve this?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes If I remove the reference from `Order` and replace it with `HasCreditCard` how do I associate `Order` with the `CreditCard` object then? I want to have `Order.CreditCard` either a value or null, I just want to avoid that in the db.

Comment: I think 'null' in the database comes from (and I'm not 100% sure on this) the fact that null actually used to take up data, but from SQL Server 2000 onward null doesn't actually use up any space so it's no long in-efficient to have nulls laying around. (I just remember reading something like that a long time ago, It's probably completely wrong.)

Comment: Also if you want to avoid a null reference in your code then it's probably a place for the Special Case pattern. http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are over thinking this.  If it were me I would just have a Reference to a credit card in my order and in my credit card entity I would have a HasMany to Orders.  If you want you can have a HasCreditCard boolean in your order that just checks if the credit card object in your order is null or not.